# How can I make a horizontal bar for statistics in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, statistics, android-recyclerview

So, I have searched the internet far and wide and I am finding no solution to my problem, despite a multitude of applications having this feature. I would like to display statistics in a visual way, like in the examples below.

[image: Flashscore statistics]

[image: All Goals statistics]

Is there a way this can be achieved? I do not mind using an external library. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe a custom view derived from the ProgressBar can do the trick, it should be easy because all you have to do is to put two progressbar along side each other and change their colors

Answer (score 0):

You can use this (just rotate one of them):

```
            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <SeekBar
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <SeekBar
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: he wants to put statistics that's mean a constant value which require a proressBar

Comment: He can do it in the same way.